# MySQLi returning less items than phpmyadmin terminal

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to use a PHP code to get stuff from a simple database but I'm facing some issues with it. :(

So, whenever I run the code below, it only returns me two lines of data (not ordered, i couldnt find any logic in it). By the other side, if I use the exact same SQL query on phpmyadmin SQL terminal, it returns me all lines with no problems.

I'm passing the parameter "v" in the url: **graph-th.php?v=4bd33036b221c9b69f13d9d0**

This is the code:

```
<?php
        include "db.php";
        $venue = $_GET['v'];
        $result = mysqli_query($dbhandle,   "SELECT * 
                                            FROM temperatures 
                                            WHERE local='$venue'
                                            ORDER BY `temperatures`.`date` DESC"
        );
        echo mysqli_num_rows($result) . "-----";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
             echo $row['date'] . ", ";
        }
        mysqli_close($dbhandle);
    ?>
```

I'm using the same idea for other SELECTs and it's working perfectly. I really cant understand why this one is not working... :/

Thanks!

Comment: First, your code is vulnerable to SQL-Injections. Escape `$venue` before inserting it into the query. Second: The code seems fine: May `v` contain ANY Special Chars like `%`? (%20 in the URL will become a whitespace in the code / query.)

Comment: @dognose I changed that line to `$venue = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbhandle, $_GET['v']);` but nothing happened yet. `v` contains no special chars or spaces, only nums and letters.

Comment: OKAY OKAY! You can call me stupid. I was connecting to the wrong database. Thanks for you help and patience.

Comment: Escaping isn't the sufficient way to avoid SQL injection; Since you're using MySQLi (which is a good thing), use [prepared statement and variable binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) should be a more appropriate way.

Comment: Thanks both of you for going beyond my question and helping me securing my code. I'll definitely take a deeper look into those things you said! :)